# Special functions, Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Well known are the Fourier expansions (presented, e.g., in Abramovitz and Stegun):
$$
\cos ( A \sin x) = J_0(A) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{2k}(A)~\cos(2kx)~~,
$$ 
$$
\sin ( A \sin x) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} J_{2k+1}(A)~\sin((2k+1)x)~~,
$$
where $\,J_v\,$ are the Bessel functions.

Similar formulae exist for $ ~\cos ( A \cos x) ~$  and  $~ \sin ( A \cos x)~$.

How to generalise them?

Ideally, it would be nice to expand functions like $ \cos ( \sum_i A_i \sin x_i)~$ or, as a starting point, to expand $\cos ( A \sin x + B \sin y)~$. In the latter, we may assume that $x$ and $y$ are commensurate, if that helps.

The simplest case needed is:
$$
\cos (~A \sin x + B \sin (x/3)~)~.
$$
What would its Fourier expansion look?

We can, of course, employ the afore-presented expansions, but then we shall have to multiply them by one another. I hope there exist a more direct and elegant solution.

Comment: FYI, those first two identities are known as [Jacobi-Anger expansions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_Anger_expansion).

Comment: Thank you! That was fast. Any idea of how to do something similar with $\cos(A\,\sin x + B \sin (x/3))~~?~~~~$                  /I mean: doing that without multiplying series./

Comment: "Well-known" can really feel like a meaningless phrase sometimes. I for one have never seen either of those identities before.

Comment: ok, agreed. Let us say:  `Well-known to those who often work with the Bessel functions.'

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: those expansions are known to anyone who works in linear systems theory, especially electrical engineers.  These equations describe frequency modulation, so they are fundamental to describing FM radio signals.

Comment: I came across these formulae in an astronomical context where they describe libration (variations of satellite's spin rate)

Comment: @RonGordon: They also show up in the context of superconductivity, specifically describing the AC Josephson effect. (See page 4 of [this paper](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~phylabs/adv/ReprintsPDF/JOS%20Reprints/06%20-%20The%20Josephson%20Junction%20as%20%20a%20Detector.pdf) for instance.)

Comment: [This paper](https://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/download/376/353.) is useful in the context you're interested in. See eq. 5 in particular.

Comment: Thank you so very much, dear Semiclassical!
I am reading this wonderful paper.

Can I please ask you for one more favour: would you
elucidate to me the meaning of the notation $\,\{x\}_1^m\,$.

/I am an astronomer, not a mathematician. So I sometimes fail to
understand notations that may look common to you guys./
Thanks again!